# Recursive Category Tree in PHP for Edit Page

Tags: php

I have created a recursive category tree in PHP, below is the code

```
function categoryTree($parent_id= 0, $sub_mark = ''){
        $stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM category WHERE cat_p_id = '".$parent_id."'");
        $stmt->execute();
        $rowCount =  $stmt->rowCount();

        if($rowCount > 0){
            while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){

                echo  '<option value="'.$row['cat_id'].'">'.$sub_mark.$row['cat_name'].'</option>';
                $this->categoryTree($row['cat_id'], $sub_mark.'--- ', '');
            }
        }
    }
```

The above code is working properly when we add Category, the problem is that when we edit the category. How to make the category selected while editing?

Below is the screenshot of the requirement:

[image]

Comment: You have to check condition in while loop like database of category(already saved) and iterate loop of category id same then "selected" string need to write into <option> else your current code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you edit page you will have the current object to edit.

```
current_object = get_current_object_somewhere();
selected_category_id = current_object->category_id;
```

So you have the `selected_category_id` you need to highlight when editing, now just need to mark it as `selected` in your select options:

```
if($rowCount > 0){
            while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
                selected = selected_category_id === $row['cat_id'] ? ' selected' : '';

                echo "<option{selected} value='{$row['cat_id']}'>{$sub_mark}{$row['cat_name']}</option>";
                $this->categoryTree($row['cat_id'], $sub_mark.'--- ', '');
            }
        }
```